# Php search through an array and return ID based records

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure if this is doable or not. I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Honda
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Toyota
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => BMW
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Ford
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Benz
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Lexus
        )
)
```

Now I need to search through an array using string like 1,3,5, find a matching id (1,3,5) and return filtered results like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Honda
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => BMW
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Benz
        )

)
```

Since there is no database involved here, I would usually do  WHERE id IN(1,2,3), but in this case that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two quick ways. Define an array of ids:

```
$ids = [1,3,5];
//or since you said string
$ids = explode(',', '1,3,5');
```

Then (since you said "filtered results") filter with an anonymous callback that compares with that array:

```
$result = array_filter($array,
                       function($o) use ($ids) {
                           return in_array($o->id, $ids, true); 
                       });
```

Or just loop, compare and create a new array:

```
foreach($array as $o) {
    if(in_array($o->id, $ids, true)) {
        $result[] = $o;
}
```

In both cases using `in_array()` I passed `true` for a strict comparison.  Not passing this may give you confusing results.  If you know that they are not both strings or both integers then remove the `true` argument as it will fail.

Comment: Thanks this partialy works, (array_filter) version, but since the id string is generated by $_POST request, it does not return anything: $ids = [$_POST['ids']];

Comment: Just replace `'1,3,5'` in the explode() with `$_POST['ids']`.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. The problem was the third parameter in in_array(), removing strict mode worked perfect.

Comment: Great that means that they are probably integers in the object.